# In JIRA, how could you search for accepted stories which are not by assigned PO?

Tags: jira, jql

I am trying to search for accepted Stories / Tasks which have been accepted or Done, but not by the assigned PO?

Comment: assigned PO ? what do you mean?

Comment: Assigned Product Owner - I am trying to find out which stories / tasks were accepted as done by the person other than the "Assigned Product Owner" for the story.

Comment: Is possible for you to use scripts for that? I guess it is not possible just with JQL, refer dinamically to APO, if this would be always the same user, would be easy. SO what about installing Script runner, and do it with a groovy script?